# Relative div in table cell

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I have positioned a div relatively in a table cell. This is given to position my absolute div(which is present inside the relative div). When I scroll the table in IE7, the relatively positioned div is not scrolling along with rows. Where as, this is working perfectly in FIrefox and IE8.

[Link to the page](http://shivanand.in/forums/table/test.html)

Comment: Wrap that div in another div.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive in your answer.